# Updating a Data Object In Vue with JavaScript doesn't trigger Vue Reactivity

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quill

I'm using Vue 2.X with the QuillJS on a project.

The Quill Editor is in a module. Inside though, I am using an event listener to do a blur on the editor itself. Quill doesn't have a blur and those solutions don't work well.

I also have a Vue class binding on the containing div.

If I tab or click in and then leave the editor, a red box with a warning label comes up as per the condition for the class binding.

The blur is checking to see if a user typed spaces and then left the editor. The blur clears out the editor, sets the Vue data object, agenda.objective, to blank and also sets the data object,agenda.showErrorObjective, to true. It is working.

However, the class isn't activated around the editor even though what triggers it is set to true.

I loaded this onto Code Pen here:
https://codepen.io/ziggythecompace/pen/jOboRQE

Thanks Donna

The code is also below.

```js
Vue.component('editor', {
  template: '<div ref="editor"></div>',
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
      default: "Please type here."
    }
  },
  data: function data() {
    return {
      editor: null
    };
  },
  mounted: function mounted() {
    var _this = this;
    this.editor = new Quill(this.$refs.editor, {
      modules: {
        keyboard: {
          bindings: {
            'tab': {
              key: 9,
              handler: function(range, context) {
                return true;
              }
            }
          }
        },
        toolbar: [
          ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', {
            'color': []
          }, {
            'background': []
          }, {
            'list': 'bullet'
          }, 'link', 'clean']
        ]
      },
      theme: 'snow',
      formats: ['bold', 'underline', 'italic', 'color', 'background', 'list', 'link', 'clean']
    });
    this.editor.root.innerHTML = this.value;
    this.editor.root.dataset.placeholder = this.placeholder;

    this.editor.on('text-change', function() {
      return _this.update();
    });

    // Prevent the event listeners from bubbling up.
    if (document.querySelector(".ql-toolbar")) {
      document.querySelector('.ql-toolbar').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        return e.preventDefault();
      });
    }

    //The below checks to see if the editors are loaded in the DOM.
    if (document.querySelector(".ql-editor")) {
      document.querySelector(".ql-editor").addEventListener('blur', function() {
        var lcEditor = document.querySelector(".ql-editor");
        var lcInput = lcEditor.innerHTML.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, '').trim();
        if (lcInput.length === 0) {
          lcEditor.innerHTML = '';
          app.$data.agenda.objective = '';
          app.$data.showErrorObjective = true;
        } else {
          app.$data.showErrorObjective = false;
        }
        console.log("showErrorObjective: " + app.$data.showErrorObjective);
      });
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update: function update() {
      const limit = 1000;
      //console.log(this.editor.getText().length);
      if (this.editor.getLength() > limit) {
        this.editor.deleteText(limit, this.editor.getLength());
      }
      this.$emit('input', this.editor.getText() ? this.editor.root.innerHTML : '');
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#vueApp',
  data: {
    agenda: {
      objective: ""
    },
    showMeetingObjective: true,
    editMeetingObjective: false,
    showErrorObjective: false,
    showValidationErrors: false
  },
  methods: {
    checkTextArea: function(id) {
      if (id === "objectives") {
        if (this.agenda.objective.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, '').trim().length === 0) {
          this.agenda.objective = "";
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}

.agenda-label {
  color: #323130;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 17px;
  text-align: left;
}

.agendaAreaEdit {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

.agendaAreaSmall {
  color: #605E5C !important;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-weight: 300 !important;
  line-height: 14px !important;
  text-align: left !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  /*height:28px;*/
  max-height: 28px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  border: none !important;
}

.agendaAreaEditor.error {
  border: 1px solid #CD0A0A !important;
}

.fa-pencil {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: #0078D4;
}

.fieldWarningLabel {
  background-color: #FDE7E9;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 16px;
  padding: 0px 8px;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  float: right;
  color: #D13438;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 14.63px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="vueApp" class="container">
  <form id="myForm">
    <div class="form-group" style="padding-top:16px;">
      <div v-bind:class="{agendaAreaEdit: editMeetingObjective}">
        <label class="agenda-label" for="purpose">Meeting Objective</label>
        <button v-if="!showMeetingObjective && !editMeetingObjective" v-on:click="showMeetingObjective=true, editMeetingObjective=true;" href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-min-padding pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        <div class="agendaAreaEditor" id="objectives" v-on:keypress="checkTextArea('objectives')" v-show="showMeetingObjective || editMeetingObjective" v-bind:class="{error: agenda.objective.trim().length===0 && (showValidationErrors || showErrorObjective)}">
          <editor v-model="agenda.objective"></editor>
        </div>
        <!--<div v-if="agenda.objective.trim().length===0 && (showValidationErrors || showErrorObjective)">-->
        <div v-if="agenda.objective.trim().length===0 && showErrorObjective">
          <label class="fieldWarningLabel">Please enter in Meeting Objectives/Purpose</label>
          <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <button v-if="showMeetingObjective && editMeetingObjective" v-on:click="showMeetingObjective=false, editMeetingObjective=false;" class="btn btn-sm btn-min-padding pull-right" style="margin: 8px 0px 0px 0px;" href="#" type="button"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"><span class="buttonText" v-html='$t("button.save")'></span></i></button>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div v-show="!showMeetingObjective" id="textarea" v-html="agenda.objective" class="agendaAreaSmall" style="height:24px;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, if your intent is to _"Prevent the event listeners from bubbling up"_, then you want `e.stopPropagation()`, **not** `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Try simply `app.showErrorObjective = true`. You really shouldn't need to directly access `$data`

Comment: Thank you. Like duh, I should have had e.stopPropagation(). But...my issue still isn't solved. If I go into the editor and out, the error warning comes up. If I type a space, and then leave the editor, it clears out the field but the error warning doesn't come up.